# react three js 3d object rotation

Tags: reactjs, animation, three.js

I have been working in this project and when i created this 3d object which should rotate as per my code is not rotating
please find the error of this code

this is my code :

```
import React , {Suspense,useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { OrbitControls ,Preload,useGLTF} from "@react-three/drei";
import canvasLoader from '../Loader'
const Computers = () => {
  const computer = useGLTF("./desktop_pc/scene.gltf");
  console.log(computer);
  return (
      <mesh>
          <hemisphereLight intensity={0.9} groundColor="black" />
          <pointLight intensity={2} />
          <spotLight position={[-20,50,20]}/>
          <primitive
              object={computer.scene}
              scale={0.65}
              position={[0, -3.25, -1.5]}
              rotation={[-0.01, -0.17, -0.1]}
          />
      </mesh>
  );
};

const ComputersCanvas = () => {
  return (
      <Canvas>

          frameloop="demand"
          shadows
          camera={{
              position: [30, 3, 5],
              fov: 25,            
          }}
          gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}>
          <Suspense >
              <OrbitControls
                  enableZoom={false}
                  maxPolarAngle={Math.PI/ 2}
                  minPolarAngle={Math.PI/2}
                  enableRotate={true}
              />
              <Computers />
          </Suspense>
          <Preload all />
      </Canvas>
  );
};
export default ComputersCanvas;
```

please check this code resolve the errors

Answer (score -1):

The code you shared does not actually contain any rotation logic. It only defines the initial rotation of the 3D model. To actually rotate the model, you need to:

```
Store the model's rotation in state
Update the rotation state over time to animate the rotation
Pass the rotation state to the model as the rotation prop
```

Here is an example:

```
  const [rotation, setRotation] = useState([0, 0, 0]);

  useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
  setRotation(prevRotation => [
  prevRotation[0] + 0.01,  // Increment x rotation by 0.01 radians
  prevRotation[1],         // Keep y rotation same
  prevRotation[2]          // Keep z rotation same
  ]);  
  }, 20);

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
  <primitive
  object={computer.scene}
  scale={0.65}
  position={[0, -3.25, -1.5]}
  rotation={rotation}  // Pass rotation state  
  />
  );
```

This will increment the x rotation by 0.01 radians every 20ms, effectively rotating the model around the x-axis.

So to fix your issue, you need to:

```
Store the rotation in state
Increment the rotation state over time using useEffect
Pass the rotation state to the <primitive> component's rotation prop
```